# Using a generalized map method to pass an element and block through returning multiple outcomes

Tags: arrays, ruby, dictionary, methods

I hope you can help me out. I am trying to understand what's going on but here is what I have to do:

Write a generalized map and reduce method. Both of these methods will take a block and require that you pass information between the method and the block.

This is what the test is looking for:

```
describe 'my own map' do
  it "returns an array with all values made negative" do
    expect(map([1, 2, 3, -9]){|n| n * -1}).to eq([-1, -2, -3, 9])
  end

  it "returns an array with the original values" do
    dune = ["paul", "gurney", "vladimir", "jessica", "chani"]
    expect(map(dune){|n| n}).to eq(dune)
  end

  it "returns an array with the original values multiplied by 2" do
    expect(map([1, 2, 3, -9]){|n| n * 2}).to eq([2, 4, 6, -18])
  end

  it "returns an array with the original values squared" do
    expect(map([1, 2, 3, -9]){|n| n * n}).to eq([1, 4, 9, 81])
  end
end
```

My code so far:

```
def map(element1) 
  element1.map { |n| n * -1 }
end
```

Now I haven't entered anything further because I need to understand how to use the same method that will be looking for different things?

Here are the errors:

```
my own map
  returns an array with all values made negative
  returns an array with the original values (FAILED - 1)
  returns an array with the original values multiplied by 2 (FAILED - 2)
  returns an array with the original values squared (FAILED - 3)

     ArgumentError:
       negative argument
     # ./lib/my_code.rb:2:in `*'
     # ./lib/my_code.rb:2:in `block in map'
     # ./lib/my_code.rb:2:in `map'
     # ./lib/my_code.rb:2:in `map'
     # ./spec/generalized_map_and_reduce_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Thank you for taking a look and any help in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: I guess you could go with `def map(element1,&block); element1.map(&block); end`. Other options include `element1.each_with_object([]) {|e, arr| arr << yield e }` or create a class, include `Enumerable`, instantiate with `element1` e.g. `def initialize(e); @element1 = e; end`, and define `each` as `def each(&block); @element1.each(&block); end`

Comment: That answered it and makes sense, the tests are passing an array and a block. Thank you

Comment: pls. conside upvoting the accepted answer (it's worth even more than accepting)

Comment: Ah thanks, wasn't aware!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `Enumerable#map` to implement your own `map`.

1. Use `while` or `for` loops or (and it'll be the best solution) `Enumerable#each`.
2. Let your `map` accept a block and the call this block inside the loop or pass it to `each`